# Unable to install CPU Sim

Tags: software-installation

I came across this error while installing cpusim3.9.0:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cpusim.util.CPUSimConstants
    at cpusim.Main.main(Main.java:135)
```

I followed this installation process:

Open a Terminal with Ctrl + Alt + T. Download the CPUSim-Zipfile:

```
wget http://www.cs.colby.edu/djskrien/CPUSim/CPUSim3.9.0.zip
```

Install unzip

```
sudo apt-get install unzip
```

Unzip the CPUSim3.9.0.zip-file

```
unzip CPUSim3.9.0.zip
```

Go into the newly created folder

```
cd CPUSim3.9.0/
```

If you haven't install a Java JRE or JDK yet, you need to install it now. If you are unsure write `java -version`. if this results with an error you must install it.

You need to first enable the universe repository. Then you can install the Java Runtime Environment (JRE).

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

Create an executable start script

```
cat <<'EOF' > cpusim
#!/bin/bash
java -cp CPUSim3.9.jar:jhall.jar:CPUSimHelp3.9.jar cpusim.Main -m SampleAssignments/Wombat1.cpu -t SampleAssignments/W1-0.a
EOF
chmod +x cpusim
```

the error came after I pressed `./cpusim`
(also I'm using ubuntu on virtual box)